# Prevent users from creating Django account with username on list

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In Django Rest Framework, I've got a post model that can be filtered by both usernames from my user object, and country names from a country objects. It just adds a `?search=` to the end of the API. From the frontend, it uses the same form to add this query onto the end of the url. I'd like to avoid confusion of returning both country names and user names that are the same. For example, if someone searched for Ireland, by preventing users from making an account with the username Ireland, it would only return Posts with country Ireland associated with the post (ManyToMany relationship to posts).

Is anything like this possible outside of creating a user for every country?

edit: Not trying to change anything with searching, trying to blacklist usernames.

Comment: Can you post your current code with a brief description of what isn't working?

Comment: It's quite common to have a blacklist of usernames that shouldn't be allowed, your question is confusing because the whole thing about countries search has nothing to do with your actual question. Basically all you need to do is hook into your `clean_username()` method in your signup form and ensure the username isn't in the black list. But it depends a bit on how you're implementing user signup and your user model, so you should be more specific.

Comment: @dirkgroten Ah right, I was just trying to give some background. My user model is simply `class User(AbstractUser):` with a home field that is a foreign key with my country model. I had to override `get_cleaned_data` in my registration serializer with one of the returns being `'username': self.validated_data.get('username', ''),` , can I do the logic here?

Comment: You want to do it during validation, so that if the username is in the blacklist, you can raise a ValidationError (which will render the field invalid and return an error to the user). If you use django-rest then just [add a custom validator to your field](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#writing-custom-validators) or define the `validate_username()` method on the serializer.

Answer (score 1):

Your data model and workflow are not entirely clear from your question, but it sounds like you could update your API View's queryset with a Q object checking if 
 ( search=country OR search=user ).

You can do this in your API View like so:

```
import from django.db.models import Q

class PostList(generics.ListAPIView):

  def get_queryset(self):
    return Post.objects.filter(
      Q(user__username=self.kwargs['search']) | \
      Q(country__name=self.kwargs['search'])
    )
```

You can read more about Q queries in the [Django Documentation for Queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

Comment: I'm filtering off of the url `search_fields = ('=author__username', 'countries__name', )` but I think in your example, if a user had a username Ireland, that would also be returned in the filter.

Comment: Your best strategy may be doing a query to see if the incoming search is a country (this is a small list and should be fast), and then changing your resulting queryset as a result.

if Country.objects.filter(name=search).exists(): 
  return Posts filtered by country
else: return filtered by username. 

You pay the penalty of the extra query, but it should be a fast one.

Comment: But if a user has a username of Ireland, then it becomes impossible to search for posts from that user. I'd rather blacklist the usernames all together.

Comment: Yes, there is no way around that one. You have one query field that can be applied to two fields. If there is an overlap you either show mixed results, or choose one, or eliminate overlaps.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

1. Install a third party library like `pycountry` which provides the countries. You can install it using `pip install pycountry`
2. In your registration serializer, update the clean method like this:

   ```
   import pycountry

   class Register(serializer.ModelSerializer):
       ....

       def validate_username(self, value):
           country = filter(lambda x: x.name.lower() == value.lower(), pycountry.countries)
           if len(list(country)) > 0:
               raise serializers.ValidationError("Invalid username")
           return value
   ```

It will check if the username is actually a country name.

Comment: I already have my country data, so I'd prefer to stick to my list, but this should get me started, thanks!